# React native app can not play mp3 after disconnecting from computer

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I save an mp3 file named 'sound1.mp3' in assets folder.
In App.js, I call:

```
let sound1 = new Sound(requires('./assets/sound1.mp3'), Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {});
sound1.play((ok) => {});
```

It worked. But when I disconnect my android phone from my computer and restart the app, it can not play mp3 file.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When we disconnect from the development server, It sometimes results in unexpected behavior. Create an APK and try with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).